# if-Statement within backticks in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I use an if Statement within the backticks?

```
let test = `Hello ${name ? '${name}' : 'unknown'}`;
```

This solution does not work though

Comment: `\`Hello ${name ? name : 'unknown'}\`` - you are using the *string* `'${name}'` otherwise, not the value of `name`

Comment: That's not an if statement ;)

Comment: there's no way to use if statement ```if (condition){}``` in templates, ternary operators only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this:

```
let test = `Hello ${name ? name : 'unknown'}`;
```

remove the single quotes to use the variable value not and not use like string.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the variable directly without a template literal.

```js
let nn = 'foo',                            // name is a reserved property of window
    test = `Hello ${nn ? nn : 'unknown'}`;
    
console.log(test);
```

Or even shorter with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()).

```js
let nn = 'foo',                            // name is a reserved property of window
    test = `Hello ${nn || 'unknown'}`;
    
console.log(test);
```